# How to wrap textarea by div and force it to be scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I need to display a lot of data in one line but i don't want to ruin my GUI.

I prepared demo:

```css
#wrapper{
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

#wrapThis{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
overflow: scroll;
resize: none
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <textarea id = "wrapThis">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

I hope you have my point i want something like that:
[image]

Can someone help me? My css's skills are really bad :<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <textarea id = "wrapThis">
  In addition to taking input data (accessed via this.props), a component can maintain internal state data (accessed via this.state). When a component’s state data changes, the rendered markup will be updated by re-invoking render().
  </textarea>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#wrapper{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#wrapThis{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  resize: none;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but there is a catch :<  I am inserting that text using Javascript if i will follow your way my text will be display only in that small area.

Comment: if you use more content you should change of wrapper width ...:-)

Comment: Yes but i want to change widht of wrapper only "inside of it" not outside  if you know what i mean

Comment: Sorry man i didn't even try your code i looked on that and i think there is no way this is gonna work, because i thinked i tried all of that moves of yours. I am so tired. Apologizes from me man! :DD It works peferect thank you so much,